# Posting an app link on Facebook wall, is not showing correct icon?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to share an app link from Google play store to my Facebook wall through my app. But when the link is posted on my wall, it shows a wrong icon.

When I am clicking the link, it is redirecting me to correct place.

```
String message = "play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+ mItem.getPackageName();
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("text/plain");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share "+mItem.getAppName()+" with your friends"));
```

Comment: What is the reason for this negative comment dude....I have done a lot of research... but could not find any satisfying answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer:

Instead of

String message = "play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+ mItem.getPackageName();

I should use the following

String msg = "https://market.android.com/search?q=pname:"+ mItem.getPackageName();

Answer (score 1):

Use this tool to check links you post on facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Facebook usually search for image tag in the header, but it's changed from time to time